# Cannot change MySQL root password

Tags: mysql

I have run the following commands found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

`shell> mysql`
`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

But when I go to login as root, I can type any string as a password, and it will still let me login.

How can I enforce a password for root, and not allow anonymous users by simply typing `mysql`

Comment: Sounds like you started the mysql server with the `--skip-grant-tables` option so you could reset the password. You need to restart it again without the option so that it will check passwords again.

Comment: Not sure how to start the server without the --skip-grant-tables option on.

Comment: Restart the server, and when you do that, don't include the option.

Comment: I never included that option when starting the server. Is there another way? Maybe this isn't the problem.

Comment: Maybe it in the `my.cnf` file? There has to be some reason why it's not checking passwords.

Comment: Anyway, questions about configuring MySQL belong on [dba.se], not [so].